# Automatization issue

Tags: python

I have different dicts:

```
    p1 = {'pair1': ([2, 3, 4], [5, 6, 7])}
    p2 = {'pair2': ([9, 10, 11], [12, 13, 14])}
    p3 = {'pair3': ([12, 20, 30], [17, 8, 30])}
```

I would like to calculate (with the saved result):

```
    p1['mean']=np.mean(p1['pair1']) 
    print p1
    {'pair1': ([2, 3, 4], [5, 6, 7]), 'mean': 4.5}
```

I would like to define a function who calculates the mean for every pair1,pair2,pair3,pair4 and saves the result.

Getting the result is not difficult, I would like to save the result in each dict.. Tried it for hours, never worked

Comment: And what have you tried so far? How did it work? What did it do instead? Did you get an error? Post the *full* traceback.

Comment: *Tried it for hours, never worked* ... For hours? Really? Strange it does not work yet... (sorry, you asked for it.. ;))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem with the question as it is currently written is that there is no way for a function to know the key name `pair1` because this is different for each dictionary.

You could use a consistent key name like `pair` for every dictionary:

```
p1 = {'pair': ([2, 3, 4], [5, 6, 7])}
p2 = {'pair': ([9, 10, 11], [12, 13, 14])}
p3 = {'pair': ([12, 20, 30], [17, 8, 30])}

def find_and_set_mean(a_dictionary):
    a_dictionary['mean']=np.mean(a_dictionary['pair']) 

find_and_set_mean(p1)
find_and_set_mean(p2)
find_and_set_mean(p3)
```

which gives:

```
{'pair': ([2, 3, 4], [5, 6, 7]), 'mean': 4.5}
{'pair': ([9, 10, 11], [12, 13, 14]), 'mean': 11.5}
{'pair': ([12, 20, 30], [17, 8, 30]), 'mean': 19.5}
```

But a better solution might be to organize this as an object:

```
class PairObject(object):

    def __init__(self, _part1, _part2):
        self.part1 = _part1
        self.part2 = _part2

    def pair(self):
        return (self.part1, self.part2)

    def mean(self):
        return np.mean((self.part1, self.part2)) 

# Then use it like this:    
p1 = PairObject([2, 3, 4], [5, 6, 7])
p1.pair() # returns ([2, 3, 4], [5, 6, 7])
p1.mean() # returns 4.5
```

Comment: Thank you! How would you organise the code? I have 50 Pairs and I need to apply 20 functions on these pairs with the results of the functions automatically added to the corresponding pair, for example, mean , correlation, rolling correlation etc. Would you rather work with sth like this?    `pairs = {'pair1':([2,3,4],[5,6,7]), 'pair2':([9,10,11],[12,13,14]), 'pair3':([5,9,10],[8,9,2])}`

Comment: I added an example of an object above. The problem with nesting too many data structures inside each other is that it becomes difficult to remember how to access the numbers and hard to debug. You could program correlation as a class function like in the above example. 
You could still store the objects in a dictionary like:
pairs['pair5'] = PairObject([3, 5], [7, 8]))

Comment: @user21988 if you've got a number of similar objects that all need to be processed in the same way, the first thing that comes to mind is using a list and applying your processing to all elements of it. If you need to access individual objects by a name, you can put them in a dict like the example you've given; but if your keys are all in the format `pair[n]` it's no different from using a list and accessing the elements by their indices...

Answer (score 0):

I want to elaborate a bit Justin's OO-solution:

The problem with the `def mean (self)` is that it will be recalculated everytime you access it. You would want to make this property lazy, i.e. calculate it when it is first accessed and the store it for future reference.

Something like this:

```
class PairObject:
    def __init__(self, part1, part2):
        self._pair = (part1, part2)
        self._mean = None

    @property
    def pair(self):
        return self._pair

    @property
    def mean(self):
        if self._mean == None: self._mean = np.mean(self._pair)
        #explicit test for None, as e.g. a mean of 0 also is falsy
        return self._mean

# Then use it like this:    
pairs = [PairObject ([2, 3, 4], [5, 6, 7]),
    PairObject ([9, 10, 11], [12, 13, 14]),
    PairObject ([12, 20, 30], [17, 8, 30]) ]

for p in pairs:
    print p.pair
    print p.mean
```